# REACTJS local server freezes my Ubuntu

Tags: intel, javascript

Whenever  my reactjs app is starting, my Ubuntu os freezes and I use Firefox not chrome because of memory management. What could be the cause? Thanks in advance.

Comment: System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV.

Comment: Ok. It freezes especially when reactjs server started with some errors in my js file.

Comment: My free Swap space is 2097148 @waltinator

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. You make it impossible for any of us to make a local copy for investigation. Rather, [Edit] your Question, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your ram is allready filled with some other program. Monitor the free ram live on your system with `top`.

You can sort the running process by ram usage by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802481/how-to-see-top-processes-sorted-by-actual-memory-usage)

Comment: I disagree that this doesn't provide an answer, but please update this comment with instructions on how to do what you're suggesting (such as opening a graphical resource monitor or using a shell command to check available memory).